# How can I get the scrollbar to move with my cursor

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to bind the cursor with the scrollbar so then when I tab to the next Text widget the window will scroll to the location of the cursor.

In my code I have many Text widgets and the window is scroll-able. I use ctrl-tab to move to the next Text widget but when the cursor is in a widget not in the window the scrollbar doesn't move. I understand I have the scrollbar bound to the mouse wheel. How can I also make the scrollbar bound to move with the cursor.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

def on_configure(event):
    # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
    # when all widgets are in canvas
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
    canvas.itemconfigure('internal_frame', width=event.width - 10)

# Create new window
new_win = tk.Tk()
new_win.focus_force()

# Create a canvas with a scrollbar
canvas = tk.Canvas(new_win)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(new_win, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(sticky=(N, S), row=0, column=1)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# --- put frame in canvas ---
new_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
new_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=new_frame, anchor='nw', tags=('internal_frame',))

# update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop when all widgets are in canvas
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
new_win.bind('<MouseWheel>', on_mousewheel)

# Add Widgets
insert_box = []
for i in range(10):
    insert_box.append(tk.Text(new_frame, borderwidth=2, height=4, width=30, wrap=WORD))
    insert_box[i].grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

# configure
new_win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
new_win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

new_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
new_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

new_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can detect the active frame and then you should be able to do some math to see if that frame is out of view and then scroll down based on that. But I am not sure there is an existing simple method to use for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move to the current `Text` widget by Ctrl+Tab or cursor, since you already have a list of `insert_box`. Just bind a `yview_moveto` command to every `Text` widget you created to `FocusIn`:

```
for i in insert_box:
    i.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda e, i=i:canvas.yview_moveto(insert_box.index(i)/len(insert_box)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works when all the boxes are the same size but when they are different sizes it starts to get a little off

Comment: This is just to show how it works in general. You can work out the exactly location by a little math; `yview_moveto` takes a float between 0-1 as parameter.

Comment: Got it, that's what i'm trying to figure out. Thank you.